# Microsoft WPF Datagrid puzzling rendering issue

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rendering

I have two WPF pages that are displayed in a master WPF window.  One page is for uploading documents (UploadDocuments), which has two tree-view components on it; one displays the categories that a document can be uploaded against and the other displays an in-page file-explorer (which I built) so that users can select which document they would like to upload.

The second page is for downloading stored documents (DownloadDocuments), which has both a tree-view for the categories documents are and would be uploaded against and the data-grid I am having an issue with.

This data-grid displays all of the documents that have been uploaded against any of the categories (when a category is selected) in the corresponding tree-view.

When the DownloadDocuments page is first entered from the master menu, the data-grid is merely displayed as empty with only the headers displayed in the header row.  The rendering of the data-grid is quite fast when coming in from the master-menu option and after any other page has been displayed that the user may have been working with.

HOWEVER, when I enter the DownloadDocuments page coming back from working with the UploadDocuments page, suddenly the rendering of the data-grid header gets increasingly slower merely to display the header row.

I have tried every suggestion I could find to rectify this issue but nothing appears to work.  And this rending issue only occurs in the DownloadDocuments page only after uploading a document or documents in the UploadDocuments page.

Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Comment: Try to profile it.

Comment: Lana... I did, thank you. And it appears that it is a Syncfusion Treeview control I am using in the DownloadDocuments page where something is going on internally with it.  As a result, it hangs the entire page.  I submitted all this information to Syncfusion Support and they are looking at it.  The profile I did showed that the Dispose functionality for the Treeview controls take an inordinate amount of time.